# Two components with the same id ‘{0}’ can’t be added to the application

Tags: ajax, asp.net-ajax

I have used one search box in tab panel.
When user click on search it will generate grid view in same tab panel.
But i want multiple such tab panel .
when i add another panel in same tab container it shows jscript error " **Two components with the same id ‘{0}’ can’t be added to the application.**"

please help on this topic.

i m open to all suggestion.
please reply.

regards,
swanand

Comment: The two panels in your tab container must not have the same `ID`.

Comment: I know but when I m setting my tab panels with different ids but on client side it is not coming as i had set. thats problem?

Comment: I know but when I m setting my tab panels with different ids but on client side it is not coming as i had set. thats problem? is this problem because of outside update panel?

Comment: can you post the code the creates the panels?

Comment: sorry but is not solved so i m making workaround using update panel in tab panel